# How to get all running process ids only?

Tags: linux, process, sed, regular-expressions

I know that

```
ps ax
```

returns the pids

```
1 ?        Ss     0:01 /sbin/init
2 ?        S<     0:00 [kthreadd]
3 ?        S<     0:00 [migration/0]
```

All I need is to clean those strings, but I couldn't do it with sed because I couldn't write the proper regex. Could you help me?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Use ps Output Formatting:**

ps -A -o pid

Output formatting of the command is the best option.  The o option controls the output formatting. I listed some of arguments below below, see 'man ps' for the rest ( to use multiple it would be `-o pid,cmd,flags`).

```
KEY   LONG         DESCRIPTION
   c     cmd          simple name of executable
   C     pcpu         cpu utilization
   f     flags        flags as in long format F field
   g     pgrp         process group ID
   G     tpgid        controlling tty process group ID
   j     cutime       cumulative user time
   J     cstime       cumulative system time
   k     utime        user time
   o     session      session ID
   p     pid          process ID
```

**Awk or Cut Would be Better to get Columns:**
Generally you wouldn't want a regex for selecting the first column, you would want to pipe it to cut or awk to cut out the first column like:

```
ps ax | awk '{print $1}'
```

**Regex is an Option, if not the best:**
If you were to use regex, it could be something like:

```
ps ax | perl -nle 'print $1 if /^ *([0-9]+)/'
```

$1 prints only what was matched in the parenthesis. ^ anchors the to the start of the line. Space asterisk means allow for optional space characters before the number.  [0-9]+ means one or more digits.  But I wouldn't recommend regex for this particular task, see why? :-)

Comment: thanks! but the regular expression would be a great addition, if anyone could contribute with a second answer

Comment: really, use awk.

Comment: Pay attention, the regex would not match the initial spaces eventually being before small pids. Moreover a pid should be make of a digit at least, not zero (you should use + and not *)

Comment: AlberT, oh good point, Didn't see that they were right justified.  That is why I said regex is not the best I guess, will fix :-)

Comment: I can't argue how to use cut, by means of the initial spaces of course. Can you point out to me how to use cut? Just for the sake of curiosity :)

Comment: Ya, guess cut doesn't work for this particular example...  But I was just make a generalization about selecting columns.  I don't really like cut though, I like awk / perl these days.

Comment: AlberT: But Actually, it can be done very elegantly with cut, see;-) num=$(ps ax | cut -f1 -d' ' | tail -1 | wc -c); ps ax | cut -c1-$num

Answer (score 6):

```
ps ax | awk '{ print $1; }'
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the **-o** switch to have a cust format output

```
ps -o pid
```

The bad way using sed, as you explicitly asked may be

```
ps -ax | sed 's#^\( *[0-9]\+\) .*$#\1#'
```

Answer (score 0):

**ps -eo pid**
or
**ps -eo %p**

-e Select all process
-o Format
    pid=process id
    %p sameas pid